# DOMDocument Method Works, XMLHTTP Method Fails - Why?

Tags: xml, vba, excel, getelementsbytagname

After setting a reference to Microsoft XML, V6.0, the following code works as expected bringing back the desired value for "buy_max"

```
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
xmlDoc.Load ("http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?typeid=24692&usesystem=30000142")

buy_max = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("buy")(0).getElementsByTagName("max")(0).Text
```

On the other hand, the following code fails to bring back a value for "buy_max".  Instead an error (Run-time error 91  "Object variable or With block variable not set") is produced.

```
my_url = "http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?typeid=24692&usesystem=30000142"
Set html_doc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
Set xml_obj = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

xml_obj.Open "GET", my_url, False
xml_obj.send
html_doc.body.innerhtml = xml_obj.ResponseText

buy_max = html_doc.getElementsByTagName("buy")(0).getElementsByTagName("max")(0).innertext
```

Can anyone explain why the second method fails?  TIA, ron

Comment: At which line do you get the exception?

Comment: When I try to execute the "buy_max = html_doc.getElementsByTagName..." line

Answer (score 2):

Well I can't explain it, but I can give you some info. I ran your code, went to the Immediate Window and type

```
?left(html_doc.body.innerHTML,50)
62</VOLUME><AVG>187369914.11</AVG><MAX>191103298.9
```

Odd that it would start after the closing tag of the first VOLUME. So I looked at the ResponseText

```
?left(xml_obj.responseText,50)
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<evec_api v
```

That starts in the right place. The HTML parser that's part of MSHTML is doing something unexpected. But I sure can't figure out why it's doing it. I figure it some problem with the quotes - like they're not really quotes. So I copied the xml and pasted into Notepad thinking that would show nonstandard characters or convert them. I saved the text file, read it into an html document and go exactly the same error.

Then I started copying less and less of the xml file into notepad - same. I got down to copying just

```
<volume>62</volume>
```

and html_doc.body.innertext returned

```
62</volume>
```

So I copied just

```
<avg>187369914.11</avg>
```

and html_doc.body.innertext returned

```
187369914.11</avg>
```

Finally, I put this in the document

```
<p><volume>62</volume></p>
```

And hmtl_doc.body.innerhtml returned

```
<P>
<P>62</VOLUME></P>
<P></P>
```

And then I gave up. Sorry that's not much of an answer, but hopefully someone else can chime in.

Answer (score 1):

**Why this fails :**

The first `.getelementsbytagname("buy")(0)` call returns a null object. The second `.getelementsbytagname` call is upon a null object and will cause error 91.

One thing that is weird is that the `ResponseText` gets implicitely split into `innerhtml` and `outerhtml` (even if you used `.innerhtml = ...`.

I'd suggest picking a tag that is present inside your `innerhtml`; let's say we choose "min". If you try `Set buy_max = html_doc.getElementsByTagName("min")(0)` and then inspect this object, you'll see that the new object `innerhtml`content is restored to what it should have been in the first place (inside the `html_doc`); But even then, any other `.getelementsbytagname` call will return a null object.

**To help debugging :**

Click `Views --> Locals Window` to help visualize the content of your objects, as well as the variables that are available to you. You need to set a breakpoint after the object has been initialized and the values have been set.

**May I ask :**

Why isn't the first solution (that's already working) not good enough?

**I will add :**

If you're simply looking for an alternative for the first solution, look in here : [HtmlDocument Class Resource (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the insight Bernard.  The first solution is fine, I was just trying to understand why the second method doesn't work.  It looks like there is just something odd about the source code behind the page.

Comment: IF my answer satisfied you, please mark the question as answered :)

Comment: I'd really like someone to explain why the source code behaves anomalously

Answer (score 1):

### What worked for me

It seems that `"HTMLFile"` instance can only be used after some kind of initialization done by the `Open` method.

**VBScript:**

```vb
Set html_doc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
html_doc.Open
' whatever you have to do
html_doc.Close
```

**JavaScript:**

```js
var html_doc = new ActiveXObject("htmlfile");
html_doc.open();
// whatever you have to do
html_doc.close();
```

### What if `Open` method is not called

In my experience, if you don't call `Open` method, then it's not possible to use some methods and properties of the objects, while other properties and methods behave normally. This is confusing, because there is no message, or error, or anything stating what to do.

- `write` method of the document does nothing or throws
- `body` property of the document is null
- `innerHTML` property of any element is null on read and throws on write
- `createElement` method of the document works
- `tagName` property of any element works